# How to set the glyph for a toolbar button to blank?

Tags: delphi

I add a toolbar with some standard Delphi components to my application. Unfortunately, the stupid arrow is first glyph (does anyone even know what it is for?)

I would like to destroy it totally, or, at least, set itcs icon to blank, so that it blends in with the toolbar.

How can I do this?

I need some code which can be executed twice without causing an exception. Thanks

Comment: If you mention the "stupid arrow" I wonder if there is something like a "smart arrow".

Comment: Nevermind - can you please explain what you are trying to achieve? I have no clue what you mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`TToolButton` gets its image from combining its `ImageIndex` property with the enclosing toolbar's `Images` property, which refers to a `TImageList`. To make a toolbar button have no image, assign `ImageIndex := -1`.

To remove the glyph from a `TSpeedButton` at design time, select the button, and then select the `Glyph` property in the Object Inspector. Press <kbd>Del</kbd> to clear the property. To do the same at run time, assign `Button.Glyph := nil`.

If you have a pre-made toolbar, such as `TMediaPlayer` or `TDBNavigator`, then you can't customize the buttons. They always show the arrow glyphs that are hard-coded in the control. You can choose to hide or show certain buttons, though. If you placed the control just to get a row of buttons and have no intention of using them to play media or navigate a database, then don't use that control. Just place a `TPanel` and put standalone buttons on it.